# Sending byte from website to serial port

Tags: serial-port, websocket, php, php-socket

How Can I send a byte from a remote website using PHP to a serial port in another computer connected to a PIC chip?

Comment: What does "btye from a remote website" mean? You didn't specify the network architecture at all, does PHP have access to the chip or not? There's a class available at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html that you can use which communicates with serial port. However, your question is too vague, add more details to it - such as what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot talk directly to the remote PC by any means other than HTTP and then only via the user's browser. Until websockets become more commonplace, that is.

Short of running a signed java applet on the client machine, there's no way for PHP to directly, or indirectly, access any hardware on a client machine.